# My webpack.config.prod.js file not generating bundle.js file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I have configured a `webpack.config.prod.js` file. I had a old version of webpack 3 where i used `ExtractTextPlugin`. I upgraded to webpack 4 where it tells me that `ExtractTextPlugin` is deprecated. I upgraded it and now using `TerserJSPlugin, MiniCssExtractPlugin and OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin`. When im running the command to build my production files, i get a long list of following errors:

`ERROR in ./src/app/appOverrides.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
CssSyntaxError`

My project folder looks like this:

[image: Project folder structure]

And my `webpack.config.prod.js` file:

```
import webpack from 'webpack'
import path from 'path'
import TerserJSPlugin from 'terser-webpack-plugin'
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from 'mini-css-extract-plugin'
import OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin from 'optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin'
import CompressionPlugin from 'compression-webpack-plugin'


const GLOBALS = {
  DEVELOPMENT : false,
  PRODUCTION: true,
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
}
export default {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      'src-gen': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src-gen'),
      'images': path.resolve(process.cwd(), './src-gen/resources')
    },
    modules: [
      path.resolve('./src'),
      path.resolve('./src-gen'),
      'node_modules'
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    'eventsource-polyfill',
    'babel-polyfill',
    './src-gen/app/index.jsx'
  ],
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/prod',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contantBase: './prod'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      filename: "[path].gz[query]",
      algorithm: "gzip",
      test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
       chunkFilename: '[id].css',
     }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserJSPlugin({}), new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/,         // Match both .js and .jsx files
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
          test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
          loaders: [
              'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
              'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optipng.optimizationLevel=4&gifsicle.interlaced=false&mozjpeg.progressive=true&pngquant.quality=75-90&pngquant.speed=3'
          ]
      },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      { test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,
         loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to load a Sass file with `css-loader` directly, which doesn't recognize SCSS syntax.

First, try installing `sass-loader` as follows:

```
npm install --save-dev sass-loader
```

or:

```
yarn add --dev sass-loader
```

Then, replace this code in `webpack.config.prod.js`:

```
{
  test: /\.s?css$/,
  use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
},
```

with the following:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    'css-loader'
  ]
},
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [
    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    'css-loader',
    'sass-loader'
  ]
},
```

This way, any `.css` files will be processed as normal straight through `css-loader`, while any `.scss` files will first be passed through `sass-loader`, which compiles Sass SCSS code into plain CSS.

Comment: Thank you for the help, i made it compile, but still some problems. I will post a new thread on that :)